# CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST and child process disassociation

Tags: cmake, ctest

Consider a package that offers some client/server functionalities. In such
a context some regression tests (as defined with `ADD_TEST(...)` ) concern
the server and some others tests concern the client. Typically, I thus need
to launch a server at the beginning of `ctest`, then to run each individual
client test, and then to cleanly kill the server (oh well, in theory :).

For this, I use `CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST` which I configured to be a shell script
(I know this is not portable but, for the time being, I don't know any
better way). This typical `CUSTOM_PRE_TEST` is of the form:

```
#!/bin/bash
the_server_to_test > log &
echo Done
```

The problem is that ctest seems to wait for the disassociation of the
child process (in this case the server I wish to test) before proceeding with
each atomic test. This can be easily checked by configuring
`CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST` with the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30 >log &
```

for which ctest will wait for 30 seconds i.e. the end of the child process
before proceeding with the test suite per se. In despair, and just to
make sure, I also tried

```
sleep 30 < /dev/null >log 2>&1 &
and in drunken despair I even tried
nohup sleep 30 < /dev/null >log 2>&1 &
```

but ctest behavior seems to always be the same...

Interestingly enough when I launch those shell scripts manually from
the command line (as opposed to launching them from within ctest) I then
get my hands back on the invoking shell while the server (on in the
above examples the sleep command) keeps on running...

My questions is thus: when using `CTEST_CUSTOM_PRE_TEST` how can one force
ctest not to wait for child process disassociation ?

Yours,
Eric Boix.

I met a problem, it was exactly same as described here, which was asked 16 years before: https://cmake.cmake.narkive.com/JLfzLWS9/ctest-custom-pre-test-and-child-process-disassociation#post1 But no answer. I pasted it here, hope someone can help

Comment: You should just be using fixtures.

Comment: Thanks for the info, fixture is the best thing to do this

Answer (score 0):

I tested it today. both below ways will not block the pre-test stage, but ctest can show up some warnings:

```
[ctest] There was an error running ctest to determine available test executables
```

```
nohup sleep 30 < /dev/null >log 2>&1 &
sleep 30 <dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

to avoid the warning, use to start a daemon, for python please use `python-daemon`, to ensure the process can exit

for example

```
python3 your_python_daemon.py >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null
```

Please be noted the stdin, stdout, and stderr should be provided other wise ctest still use their own one and wait it to be close, which can still block the pre-test stage

As mentioned by @KamilCuk, ctest fixture is the best facility to implement this task. be aware that when starting daemon in ctest fixture, stdin, stdout and stderr also need to be proved like above